# Custom autoescaper in Symfony 2

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, twig

I need to add to Symfony 2 default autoescaper an ability to escape double curly brackets {{ and }}. So it should work **without any modifications inside twig templates**.

I've tried to add custom escaper as

```
$twig->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Core')->setEscaper('angular-html', $escaper);
```

and replace default escaping strategy "html" with custom "angular-html"

```
class AngularEscapingStrategy
{
    public static function guess($name)
    {
        $strategy = \Twig_FileExtensionEscapingStrategy::guess($name);
        return ($strategy === 'html') ? 'angular-html' : $strategy;
    }
}
```

So it works, but twig built-in functions like form_row or nl2br require escaper name to be equal 'html' to work properly:

```
new Twig_SimpleFilter('nl2br', 'nl2br', array('pre_escape' => 'html', 'is_safe' => array('html'))),
```

Is there any other way to extend default "html" escaper and keep its name?

Comment: Did you try setEscaper('html',$myEscaper) ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work: looks like default escapers are hardcoded and can't be redefined, see https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php#L910

Comment: Well that sucks.  I don't even see the html escaper being defined as a service so you can't override the service definition.  Might want to rethink why you want to escape the double brackets.